# getObjectByName in traverse THREE.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

How could I use *.name property in parent/child case at traverse function?
oLoader.load() is asynchronous. By the time I am doing object.traverse() the object hasn't loaded yet.
How could I fix it?

This works :

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 32, 32);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffff00});
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
sphere.name = 'gomb';
scene.add(sphere);

var obj = scene.getObjectByName('gomb');
function remove(obj) {
    scene.remove(obj);
}
remove(obj);
```

But this does not work :

```
var oLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
oLoader.load('model/0004_02_00_FF_00_xxxxxx_0_00.obj', function (object, materials) {
    var material_this = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x00FF00});
    object.traverse(function (child) {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
            child.material = material_this;
            child.castShadow = true;
            child.receiveShadow = true;
        }
    });

    object.position.x = 0;
    object.position.y = 0;
    object.position.z = 0;
    object.name = '0004_02_00_FF_00_xxxxxx_0_00';
    scene.add(object);
});

var obj = scene.getObjectByName('0004_02_00_FF_00_xxxxxx_0_00', true);
function remove(obj) {
    scene.remove(obj);
}
remove(obj);
```

Comment: When you call `remove()`, the object may not have loaded yet. When you call `traverse()` in the loader callback, the object has loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick is to immediately add a named parent to the scene when you start loading your object and check that the parent still exists when the loading ends.

```
function loadObj(name, url, scene) {
    var parent = new THREE.Object3D();
    parent.name = name;
    scene.add(parent);

    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.load(url, function (object) {
        var parent = scene.getObjectByName(name);
        if (parent) {
            parent.add(object);
        }
    });
}
```

You're know able to remove it, event if the object is loading.

```
loadObj('my_object', 'model/0004_02_00_FF_00_xxxxxx_0_00.obj', scene);
var obj = scene.getObjectByName('my_object');
scene.remove(obj);
```

Note that this requires to know the name of your object by the time you load it.